# Average across matrices within a structures

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, cell-array

I have a structure **P** with 20 matrices. Each matrix is `53x63x46` double. The names of the matrices are fairly random, for instance S154, S324, S412, etc. Is there any way I can do an average across these matrices without having to type out like this?

```
M=(P.S154 + P.S324 + P.S412 + ...)/20
```

Also, does it make sense to use structure for computation like this. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033702/matlab-structure-with-6x6-matrices-how-to-get-the-average-across-the-group), perhaps it should be converted to cell array.

Comment: This link could be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803962/iterating-through-struct-fieldnames-in-matlab

Comment: excaza, I would like to get the average of all matrices. My M example is the average of 20 matrices within structure P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct2cell(P)
```

is a cell array each of whose elements is one of your structure fields (the field names are discarded). Then

```
cell2mat(struct2cell(P))
```

is the result of concatenating these matrices along the first axis. You might reasonably ask why it does that rather than, say, making a new axis and giving you a 4-dimensional array, but expecting sensible answers to such questions is asking for frustration. Anyway, unless I'm getting the dimensions muddled,

```
reshape(cell2mat(struct2cell(P)),[53 20 63 46])))
```

will then give you roughly the 4-dimensional array you're after, with the "new" axis being (of *course*!) number 2. So now

```
mean(reshape(cell2mat(struct2cell(P)),[53 20 63 46]),2)
```

will compute the mean along that axis. The result will have shape `[53 1 63 46]`, so now you will need to fix up the axes again:

```
reshape(mean(reshape(cell2mat(struct2cell(P)),[53 20 63 46]),2),[53 63 46])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using structures, and by your question, you have fieldnames for each matrix.

Therefore, you need to:

1 - use function `fieldnames` to extract all the matrix names inside your structure. - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html

2- then you can access it by doing like:

```
names = fieldnames(P);
matrix1 = P.names{1}
```

Using a for loop you can then make your calculations pretty fast!